# node ftpd and pasv through docker-compose won't connect when run locally

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I get the following errors when using filezilla to access an ftp server that's set up through node ftpd and deployed on a docker container:

From the filezilla side I get:

```
Error:    The data connection could not be established: ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server
Response:    150 Here comes the directory listing
Error:    Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:    Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

and from the container I get:

```
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> >> 230 User logged in, proceed.
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> << OPTS UTF8 ON
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> FTP command: OPTS UTF8 ON
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> >> 200 OK
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> << PBSZ 0
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> FTP command: PBSZ 0
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> >> 200 OK
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> << PROT P
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> FTP command: PROT P
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> >> 200 OK
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> << PWD
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> FTP command: PWD
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> >> 257 "/" is current directory
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> << TYPE I
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> FTP command: TYPE I
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> >> 200 OK
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> << PASV
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> FTP command: PASV
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> Setting up listener for passive connections
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> Passive data connection beginning to listen
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> Passive data connection listening on port 1025
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> >> 227 Entering Passive Mode (172,18,0,6,4,1)
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> << LIST
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> FTP command: LIST
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> Directory has 2 files
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> >> 150 Here comes the directory listing
livedatawriter_1  | <::ffff:172.18.0.1> Currently no data connection; expecting client to connect to pasv server shortly...
```

All ports are open and I don't have any firewalls running. Wondering if this is a problem with the request coming back for the internal docker network address and not for localhost as I make the request from local host but the response comes from the internal address. Strange thing is this works when deployed on the server with DCOS.

The compose segment looks like this:

```
  livedatawriter:
    extends:
      file: docker-compose-aws.yml
      service: aws
    build: ../LiveDataWriter
    ports:
      - "9004:9004"
      - "7002:7002"
      - "1025-1050:1025-1050"
      - "51343:51343"
    entrypoint: ["npm", "run", "debug"]
    links:
      - postgres
      - auth
      - redis
      - kafka
    depends_on:
      - auth
    environment:
      HOST: "auth"
      POSTGRES_HOST: "postgres"
      REDIS_HOST: "redis"
      KAFKA_BROKER_IPS: "kafka:9092"
      FTP_HOST: "172.18.0.6"
      FTP_PORT: 7002
      FTP_BASEFOLDER: "/temp"
      FTP_LOGLEVEL: 4
      DATA_SERVICE_HTTPS: "false"
      DATA_SERVICE_URL: "proxy:8081"
```